# Unable to obtain driver for chrome using selenium manager

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Update - I did get it to work by manually downloading chromedriver, per the selenium webdriver recommendations. The path environment variable method didn't work even though it did successfully pass the test for chromedriver version: –

*To see what directories are already on PATH, open a Command Prompt and execute:
echo %PATH%
If the location to your driver is not already in a directory listed, you can add a new directory to PATH:
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\WebDriver\bin"
You can test if it has been added correctly by checking the version of the driver:
chromedriver.exe --version*

What did work was specifying the location of the downloaded driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pandas as pd

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chromedriver_bin = 'C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/chromedriver.exe'
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=chromedriver_bin)

# service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

I feel like this is not the optimum solution - by the way my chrome version is 120.0.6099.71 and I think my problems may have started after the latest update.

OS Windows 10
Selenium version 4.11.2
Python 3.9.13
PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2 IDE

All of a sudden I'm getting an unable to obtain driver error when trying to execute the driver = webdriver line:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# import time
# import pandas as pd
#
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

the output looks like (I pasted the full output at the bottom):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.2\scratches\scratch.py", line 10, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in **init**
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 44, in get_path
raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: **Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager**.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

I did do windows system restore to a couple of weeks ago, no apparent help.  I tried a lame attempt at troubleshooting by adding a few print commands to the driver_finder file:

```
@staticmethod
    def get_path(service: Service, options: BaseOptions) -> str:
        path = service.path
        
        #  troubleshoot
        print('path = ', path)
        print('service = ', service)
        print('options = ', options)
        
        
        try:
            path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
        except Exception as err:
            msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
            raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err

        if path is None or not Path(path).is_file():
            raise NoSuchDriverException(f"Unable to locate or obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']}")

        return path
```

and get this:

path =  None
service =  <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x00000219CB67AD30>
options =  <selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options object at 0x00000219CB6985B0>

Thanks!

full output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 126, in run
output = json.loads(stdout)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 90, in driver_location
output = self.run(args)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 129, in run
raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}") from err
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.2\scratches\scratch.py", line 10, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in **init**
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 44, in get_path
raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location